# Is it possible to get half the space (height or width) without weights?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Using a linear layout is it possible to get half the size of the e.g. height without having a widget following (i.e. no weights to use)?
I.e.

```
 ________________                    
|                | 
|                |                                      
|                |                  
|           _____|                            
|          |                   
|          |                             
|__________|
```

Comment: Do you really need not to have anything following?  Can you just put a View after it and use weights?  You won't see it.

Comment: @MarkSmith:You mean with no background color?

Comment: I can't understand what you mean to say...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "with no background colour".  If you have a View (not one of its subclasses - an actual View) in your layout, you can use its weights, but it doesn't have a manifestation on the screen.  I've used this before for just this sort of thing.  Diva's solution sounds perhaps a bit cleaner, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont wanna use linear layout , Use Relative Layout like below :

Create Relative Layout as Main Parent Layout

1. Place a layout in middle of layout say 1 dp in height and match_parent in width and give property as    `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`
   [Relative Layout]
2. Place a Layout above this line [Any Layout linear or Relative]
3. Place a Layout below this line [Any Layout linear or Relative]

This will spit the layout equally in 2 half without linear layout

Basically this is how it should look like :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/sepertaor" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/sepertaor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sepertaor" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `Place a layout in middle of layout` what layouts are these?

Comment: this would be seperator

Comment: what should be the height of the layout which is above the line and bellow the line ..

Comment: How would I make the height to be 1/3 of the total height in the anchor relative layout instead of using height `1dp`? Same question for width instead of `match_parent`

Comment: Or the idea is to use this layout only to position above/bellow?In that case I don’t want to place that separator to the middle but 1/3 of the height